# Firebase, decoded idToken is not the same as the token sent with REST

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

i am using firebase realtime database for my projects backend, but i have come upon a problem with making the security rules. I use REST to communicate with the database and to authorize the REST request i send an idToken as the query of the "auth=" parameter, as per https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth.

Firebase only detects that i am authorized, but when i compare the auth.uid in the database rules they are not the same. I set up my own server and if i decode the token i see that it does hold the correct information of the user.

Here are my database rules i want to implement but they don't work:

```
{
  "rules": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid === $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid === $uid"
      }
  }
}
```

But these rules do work, which means i am authorized. Why does the auth object not hold the actual user id but some other value for auth.uid?

```
  "rules": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null"
      }
  }
}
```

Why does firebase decode the token differently? Can i even access the auth object that gets sent to the rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `auth` object has 3 properties as listed below:

| name | description |
| --- | --- |
| provider | The authentication method used ("password", "anonymous", "facebook", "github", "google", or "twitter"). |
| uid | A unique user id, guaranteed to be unique across all providers. |
| token | The contents of the Firebase Auth ID token. See the reference documentation for auth.token for more details. |

To access the *decoded token* including custom claims you can use `auth.token`. You can find more details about `auth.token` object in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#authtoken)

---

Since your data is under a node `'data'`, you must specify that in rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "data": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid === $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid === $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: useful documentation link, but i still can't get it to work even if i use the rule: ".read": "auth.token.sub === $uid". the id in the token and the name of the folder i want to read don't match... could this maybe be a problem in my data structure in the database?

Comment: @RomanKolar you can access UID of directly by `auth.uid` but please share a screenshot of your database

Comment: https://imgur.com/gallery/bgSsiDH, i tried "auth.uid === 'l51zB8vjPGc9QQ8DGNhUEfJSG7B3'" which is my ID and it works, but if use the $uid it doesnt?

Comment: @RomanKolar your rules are not defined for `data` node. it's expecting UID as root key.. can you share complete DB structure including root nodes?

Comment: Omg you are a savior... I was reading the documentation and i swear it said the root folder does not have to be included in the rules... Thanks alot man, can't believe i wasted so much time on this... :)

Comment: the screenshot is the whole data structure btw

Comment: @RomanKolar yes just wanted to make sure if `data` node had a parent node.